# Create a specific number pattern using matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, math, octave, numerical-methods

How can I create a specific number pattern?  Where the last number starts the 2nd pattern section.

Example:

**I want to follow / repeat the pattern 1,5,4**

```
1st pattern in section 1,5,4
2nd pattern in section 5,9,8
3rd pattern in section 9,13,12

final array would be = [1,5,4,5,9,8,9,13,12,...]
```

**note: this is just a simple example the pattern will be about 100,000 + numbers**

I know about repmat and cumsum but combining these two didn't work

PS:  I'm using Octave 4.2.2 which is similar to Matlab

Comment: `[1,5,4]+[0;4;8]`?

Comment: @Daniel [1,5,4]+[last number + 1, +4, -1]

Comment: I don't understand you comment. Isn't the code I pasted generating the numbers you need?

Comment: @Daniel yes thanks, but how does one increase the pattern out `n` more times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x=reshape([1;5;4]+[0:4:n*4],1,[])
```

When you take a look at your question, each row is [1;5;4] incremented by a multiple of 4. That is what above code does, adds [1;5;4] with a multiple of 4. Finally the result is reshaped to a vector.